# can't resize widgets in QVBoxLayout

Tags: qt

I have a container widget with a QVBoxLayout.

I have about 100 widgets added into the VBoxLayout. They all have the same height.
At some point there's a need to resize one of the rows. I resize(newWidth, newHeight) the widget and call layout() on the QVBoxLayout, but nothing changes. the size remains fixed.

How do I dynamically change the height of widgets in QVBoxLayout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A resize of a widget that is inserted in a layout is a no-op, by design. The layout sizes the widgets, not you.

If you want a fixed-height widget in a QVBoxLayout, you have to set the widget's minimum and maximum height, and ensure its sizePolicy is not ignored in vertical direction.

If you want a widget that's twice the height of all other widgets. Set its stretch to 2, and stretch of other widgets to 1. Call `layout->setStretch(index, stretch)`. The widgets will be assigned width proportionally to their stretches. For example, with all stretches at 1 and one stretch at 2, the widget with stretch 2 will get twice the room.

Everything else being equal (that's the important bit!), stretches are proportional to pixel sizes of widgets. If you want, say all widgets to be 20 pixels tall, but one to be 30 pixels tall, just set their stretches like so.

If the layout has the exact height so that the sum of all widget heights + spacings + margins adds up to layout height, you'll get height=stretch for widgets in the layout. Conversely, if you start with layout height, subtract the top and bottom margins and (widget count - 1)*spacing, you'll have height left for the widgets. You can then manually distribute that height among the widgets by setting stretch equal to desired height.

You may need to override the `sizePolicy` of the widgets, if they are too big by default.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not do anything. there is no effect on the height of my widgets when i setStretch,

Comment: Did you call it on all of the widgets in the layout? You should also set the sizePolicy of all widgets to ignored in both directions, at least initially.

Comment: setting size policy to 'ignored' for both directions improves things. but i'm still getting underministic results. a stretch of 2, grows things by 3. things never shrink back when set back to 1. it's unstable. it only works on every other widget, not all. very strange behavior. there is no chance i can get to the bottom of this behavior in without spending weeks on this. I may have to design my own custom layout. Qt's simply doesn't work well. I'm surprised that changing the height of a widget in a layout would be such a phD level task.