# Qt: resize(int,int) doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, resize

```
qconnectorblob::qconnectorblob(QWidget *parent, bool type,
                               QNodeWidget *myPWidget, long myID, long connectToID) :
    QRadioButton(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    this->setAutoExclusive(false);
    mNodeWidget = myPWidget;
    mtype = type;

    //Resize for Android
    this->resize(40,40);
```

What i've to update that "this" resizes ?
The parent widget ? "This" widget ?
Or both ? how can I cause a redraw event with my 40x40 size ?

Just tried this but the widget-"sprite/image" dont change its size:

```
//Resize for Android
this->setFixedSize(40,40);
this->setMinimumSize(40,40);
this->setMaximumSize(40,40);
this->resize(40,40);
this->repaint();
```

Comment: Setfixedsize set min and max sizes. If you use layouts check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000083/cant-resize-widgets-in-qvboxlayout also try to use resizeEvent, not paintEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You resize qconnectorblob widget, not a parent. From doc:

> size : QSize
>   This property holds the size of the widget excluding any window frame.
>   If the widget is visible when it is being resized, it receives a resize event (resizeEvent()) immediately. If the widget is not currently visible, it is guaranteed to receive an event before it is shown.
>   The size is adjusted if it lies outside the range defined by minimumSize() and maximumSize().
>   By default, this property contains a value that depends on the user's platform and screen geometry.
>   Warning: Calling resize() or setGeometry() inside resizeEvent() can lead to infinite recursion.
>   Note: Setting the size to QSize(0, 0) will cause the widget to not appear on screen. This also applies to windows.

So you can reimplement resizeEvent and do something in this event. You also can call repaint(), it will call paintEvent, but I think that resizeEvent is more suitable.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#repaint

Example of usage:

```
void MyButton::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("QRadioButton {"
                        "color: rgb("+QString::number(qrand()%255)+","+QString::number(qrand()%255)+","+QString::number(qrand()%255)+");"
                        "background-color: rgb("+QString::number(qrand()%255)+","+QString::number(qrand()%255)+","+QString::number(qrand()%255)+')'
                       +"}");
}
```

Button will have new random color every resizing.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit use of `repaint` is almost always a bug. Certainly it is in this case. Just get rid of that line.

You need to decide whether you manually size the widget, or whether it is sized by the layouts. The two can't coexist at the same time. If the widget is managed by a layout, the explicit `resize` call is a no-op. If the widget is not managed by a layout, then the `setXxxxSize` calls are no-ops, since they merely set properties that are consumed by the layout system.