# resize() not applying / working on Widgets that are part of layout

Tags: c++, qt

I have following code:

```
main_layout_.setSpacing(0);
main_layout_.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
main_layout_.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
auto btn = new QPushButton("btn");
btn->resize(80,80);
main_layout_.addWidget(btn);
main_layout_.addWidget(new QPushButton("btn"));
main_layout_.addWidget(new QPushButton("btn"));
main_layout_.addWidget(new QPushButton("btn"));
centralWidget()->setLayout(&main_layout_);
```

The problem is that `btn->resize(80,80);` is not applying. I tried to add next lines:

```
main_layout_.setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);
btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
```

I also tried all QSizePolicy flags but with no result.
What am I dooing wrong? How can I set the desired size for any button I want?
**P.S.** Using `setMinimumSize()` or `setFixedSize()` is not an option, because this way buttons will tend to ignore resize queries from externals factors.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000083/cant-resize-widgets-in-qvboxlayout

Comment: If you want to manually set the size of things (i.e. *lay them out*), then don't use a *layout*.

Comment: If I will modify the sizeHint for buttons inside layout, would they have the size I set as hint size? Or still the minimum size will be used?

Answer (score 0):

As dom0 said, don't use layout if you want to apply size by yourself. If you still want to apply layout and fix size, you'll **have to** play with `setMinimumSize()` and reassign it manually (via a slot for example) every time the parent's size change.