# How to change layout size in main window?

Tags: c++, qt

I've created a `QVBoxLayout` in mainwindow and put the video player widget into it. But when I try to change the size of the window, the layout's size does not want to change. How to change it?

```
player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
vw = new VideoWidget(this);
player->setVideoOutput(vw);
ui->playerLayout->addWidget(vw);
```

Comment: if you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], also for this type of cases it is advisable to show images that illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Jacek Duraj possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000083/cant-resize-widgets-in-qvboxlayout